# Linking a nasm hello world program by using gcc causes linking errors

Tags: gcc, assembly, x86, nasm

I have a problem. Whenever I try to link my assembly program I get errors. I want to use C-Functions with the Netwide assembly but it doesn't work under Windows with Mingw-w64. I don't understand this because the same code works under Linux with Nasm and gcc

```
section .data
    msg:        db          'Hello World', 0xa, 0x0

section .text
    global main
    extern printf

main:
    push    msg
    call    printf
    add     esp, 4

    ret
```

I'm using windows with nasm assembler and want to compile my program into a 32 bit application

I typed this

```
nasm -fwin32 hello_world.asm
```

and it works
and then:
and it doesn't work
    gcc -m32 -o hello_world.exe hello_world.obj

But I got this big error message:

```
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingw32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0\libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/libgcc_eh.a when searching for -lgcc_eh
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0\libgcc_eh.a when searching for -lgcc_eh
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/libgcc_eh.a when searching for -lgcc_eh
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_eh
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmoldname
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingwex
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmsvcrt
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libpthread.dll.a when searching for -lpthread
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libpthread.a when searching for -lpthread
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libpthread.a when searching for -lpthread
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libpthread.dll.a when searching for -lpthread
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libpthread.a when searching for -lpthread
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lpthread
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libadvapi32.a when searching for -ladvapi32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -ladvapi32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libshell32.a when searching for -lshell32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lshell32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libuser32.a when searching for -luser32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -luser32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libkernel32.a when searching for -lkernel32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lkernel32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libiconv.a when searching for -liconv
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -liconv
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingw32.a when searching for -lmingw32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingw32
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0\libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/libgcc.a when searching for -lgcc
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/libgcc_eh.a when searching for -lgcc_eh
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0\libgcc_eh.a when searching for -lgcc_eh
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/libgcc_eh.a when searching for -lgcc_eh
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lgcc_eh
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmoldname.a when searching for -lmoldname
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmoldname
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmingwex.a when searching for -lmingwex
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmingwex
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib\libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib/libmsvcrt.a when searching for -lmsvcrt
C:/Program Files/mingw-w64/x86_64-7.1.0-posix-seh-rt_v5-rev0/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/7.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmsvcrt
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What can I do? I don't know how to fix this

Thanks for each help

Comment: It seems that gcc couldn't find its libraries. Try to reinstall your MinGW toolchain.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this appears to be an installation/path issue, not a programming problem.

Comment: The problem is that my gcc is able to link c programs but not able to link an asm program

Comment: When you say it worked with a GCC program were you creating a 32-bit program or 64-bit? It almost appears your GCC might have only been installed with 64-bit support. Possibly there is a multilib version of GCC available for your environment or you need a 32-bit version of the compiler and linker. What does `gcc -v` show?

Comment: According to MinGW w64 my compiler must support both versions but gcc -v says that it only supports x86_64. this is weird

Comment: What happens when you `gcc -m32 hello.c -o hello_32bit.exe`?  Your compiler itself can produce 32 or 64-bit object files (because gcc does both from the same `cc1` executable controlled by `-m64` and `-m32`), but the question is whether you have the 32-bit libraries installed for it to link with.